# competing risks model with ties

Tags: survival, competing-risks

I am fitting a competing risks survival model on a data set. There are 3 types of failures that compete with each other and occurrence of the first event is defined as the failure status. However, I just have the survival times in year (no month, no day) then for some observations the survival times for two or three compete events would be the same. How can I impute failure type for this observations?

Any help would be appreciated.